# How to systematically reproduce the deadlock on neo4j with cypher?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I'm getting a deadlock issue, and I want a way to make each query take longer so I can systematically reproduce the deadlock. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that using Cypher? I could be either creating a temporary lock the node each time, or making a query that takes longer to execute?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I tried using the `apoc.lock` method, and this is the query I end up with:

```
    sb.append("MERGE (user:User {id: {1}}) ON CREATE SET user.id = {1}, user.name = {2}, user.createTime = timestamp()");
    sb.append(" WITH user AS user CALL apoc.lock.nodes([user])");
    sb.append(" MERGE (user2:User {id: {1}}) ON MATCH SET user2.updateTime = timestamp()");
    sb.append(" MERGE (session:Session {id: {3}}) ON CREATE SET session.id = {3}");
    sb.append(" MERGE (user)-[:STARTED]->(session)");

    sb.append(" WITH 5000 AS duration CALL apoc.util.sleep(duration)");    
    sb.append(" MERGE (user3:User {id: {1}}) ON MATCH SET user3.closeTime = timestamp(), user3.timeDiff = user3.closeTime - user3.createTime");
```

Comment: As I recall, `timestamp()` will return the instant of query execution, not statement execution, so don't expect different timestamps in the same query to be different. Also, you won't be able to engage a deadlock within just a single query. You'll need to be running concurrent queries in order to trigger something.

Comment: Yep, I just find out about that. Thank you for the help

Comment: Add to what I just said, I was still not able to reproduce a deadlock. I tried to run the above code, and run  `MERGE (user2:User {id: {1}}) ON MATCH SET user2.updateTime = timestamp()` immediately. The update was able to run, but at a much later time than creation time. It seems like the queries were lining up instead of hitting the deadlock. Running the first query for multiple times also has the same result. It could be because I was running the code either in neo4j browser or creating a seperate driver for each query

Comment: This wasn't a deadlock, just contention for a lock that could be resolved by waiting for one query to finish. To initiate a deadlock, you have to have two queries that start to grab locks, but then they can't grab another lock because they're both waiting on each other. For example, query 1 locks on Node A and sleeps, after which it will attempt to lock on Node B, and concurrently query 2 locks on Node B and sleeps, after which it will attempt to lock on Node A. Neither can complete because they're waiting on each other's locks, and won't release the locks they currently have.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) has [apoc.util.sleep()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_utilities), which you can call within a Cypher query to sleep for some number of milliseconds

For example:

```
...
// after cypher which obtains locks
CALL apoc.util.sleep(5000) // sleep 5 seconds
```

APOC also has procedures for [locking on nodes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_locking).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder after obtaining the lock, when would the lock be released?

Comment: Once acquired (either through an APOC locking operation or through a write operation in Cypher) locks persist to the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of concurrent requests and/or repeat the same requests many times.

There are APOC procedures that help with the latter. For example, [apoc.periodic.repeat](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_further_functions) will repeatedly execute the same Cypher statement until you call `apoc.periodic.cancel` to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add in that APOC has a run Cypher ([apoc.cypher.run](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_cypher_operations)), So you can get a write lock on a node, and then use APOC to recursively do another write on it and that should create a deadlock.